# hibernation or suspension during system logged out prevent form network connection ssh

Tags: debian, ssh, hibernate

Debian 11 bullseye

I know there are 1008 threads on hibernation only in Unix&Linux. However, I could not find the answer to my problem.

I cannot SSH my PC when it is logged out. I suspect this is because it is in suspension/hibernation.

If I am logged in, the PC does not go to hibernation/suspension (disabled in settings), and SSH works.

After logging out, the PC will go to suspension/hibernation.

How can I disable suspension/hibernation when I am logged out? so Linux responds to network ssh?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer

-Using settings will only change the behavior while the account is logged in

- Then, there is the login screen or **greeter session**

To change the setting in the greeter session, and in gnome, edit the file:

```
 /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
```

In this file, there is the configuration:

```
# Automatic suspend
# =================
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
# - Time inactive in seconds before suspending with AC power
#   1200=20 minutes, 0=never
# sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=1200
# - What to do after sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
#   'blank', 'suspend', 'shutdown', 'hibernate', 'interactive' or 'nothing'
# sleep-inactive-ac-type='suspend'
# - As above but when on battery
# sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=1200
# sleep-inactive-battery-type='suspend'
sleep-inactive-battery-type='blank'
```

I set the sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0